# Catch ENOENT when using express and serve-index

Tags: node.js, express, file-not-found

I've been learning React and working on an interface where the user can view some of the files on a server using the `serve-index` package and custom styling.

The relevant portion of the code is below:

```
app.use('/files', serveIndex(__dirname + '/files', {
    stylesheet: "directory-style.css",
    icons: true
}));

app.get('/files/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(req.url.substr(7), {root: `${__dirname}/files`});
});
```

Unfortunately, if the URL is not a valid filename, the user will see an error message similar to the following:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\full\path\to\my\react\app\on\server'
```

which could be a security concern.

Is there a way to avoid exposing this full path, or should I be using an alternative to `serve-index`?

I've tried enclosing various portions of the code in `try-catch` blocks but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I was able to resolve this issue with the following code under the file retrieval method:

```
app.get('/files/*', (req, res) => {
    let path = req.url.substr(7);
    let fileRoot = `${__dirname}/files`;
    if (fs.existsSync(fileRoot + "/" + path)) {
        res.sendFile(path, {root: fileRoot});
    } else {
        res.send(`File or directory "${path}" not found!`);
    }
});
```